# Getting reference of the list item which initiated the dialog

Tags: android, android-listview, android-dialog

I have a list view on which I have attached a long click listener. In this long click listener I am showing a pop up menu to the user with options such as "Delete". When the delete is pressed from that menu, I need reference to the view of the list item which triggered the long click listener so that I can delete that list item. I need the reference in the inner on click listener. How can I do it, Please help. here is my code.

```
listview.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {
@Override
public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
   CharSequence options[]={"Delete"};
   AlertDialog.Builder symbolOptions=new Builder(context);
   symbolOptions.setItems(options, new OnClickListener() {
   @Override
   public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
      CharSequence options[]={"Delete"};
      AlertDialog.Builder symbolOptions=new Builder(context);
      symbolOptions.setItems(options, new OnClickListener() {
      public void onClick(DialogInterface thisDialog, int which) {
         //TODO Auto-generated method stub 
         switch (which) {
         case 0:
         //Reference to the list item which initiated the long click listener
         // Delete that list item
      break;
      default:
         thisDialog.dismiss();
      break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this...

put all the ids of the list items in a ArrayList. Say....

```
ArrayList<Integer> itemids = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

Then in the onItemLongClick...

```
int selected_item_id = itemids.get(position);
```

Now you know the id of the item you clicked. Hope it helps.

Comment: Wont work because I want that id to be used in yet another method, that is onclick.

Comment: I think you can get the id in other method, if you declare the selected_item_id globally.

Comment: Have you solved this already? Please share if you can do it. It will be helpful for me.

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem by saving the position and item name as global variables of that class and  then accessed them from the inner function. I don't know if this is the right way or not, but I think this being a very common feature, there should be a better way of doing this. For now, I have to stay with this.